# VLC Screenshot capture no longer working (only green and purple junk now)

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player, screenshot, screen-capture

Suddenly all my screen captures look like green and purple junk. See the image below.

Running Ubuntu Linux 21.04 with KDE. (I don't know if I'm running Wayland or X-Server but it's been working great for over a year until just now.)

- VLC version 3.0.12.
- My last good confirmed Screenshot was from 2021-06-20.
- My GPU is Radeon RX 580 Series, OpenGL 4.6.
- Monitors are 4k LG.

Anyone know what's wrong?

[image: green purple junk]

---

**Update**: It seemed that updating for a later version of VLC did solve the issue. This now work. Overall I updated my whole system to a later version of Ubuntu also, so if any driver updates happened under the hood, those might have been relevant as well.

Comment: Are you able to upgrade to VLC version 3.0.14 ?  I was not certain from the VLC article. Can you try the Chromium browser?

Comment: @John I tried using the latest version of VLC from SNAP and it seemed to capture alright. I will update when that version reaches the Ubuntu repositories. It may just be a version glitch with my system for some reason. If the problem persists, then it is probably a configuration issue. I wonder where SNAP program user-configurations are stored?

Comment: It seemed that updating for a later version of VLC did solve the issue. Overall I updated my whole system to a later version of Ubuntu also, so if any driver updates happened under the hood, those might have been relevant as well.

Comment: This is now an older question. Did my answer solve the issue for you?

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to set “Preferences > Input / Codecs > Hardware-accelerated decoding” to `Disabled`.

Source:

- https://davescomputertips.com/how-to-fix-vlc-crashing-when-taking-screenshot/

Comment: Does not help on Ubuntu 20.04 with VLC 3.0.9.2

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. My environment is Ubuntu 22.04.3 where this helped. Please keep looking, and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem on Ubuntu 20.04 with VLC 3.0.9.2: screenshots from a video was all black.
Disabling `Hardware-accelerated decoding` option does not help.

Updating to the last version (VLC 3.0.19) as recommended by [C.D. in the update section of the current question](https://superuser.com/q/1661301/238462) helped.

I had to install this version from `snap`:

```
sudo snap install vlc
```

Because as described on [the official VLC site](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html) the last version is available only from there.

After installing new version of VLC I have two versions available to run - one from `apt` and the other from `snap`. Will be using VLC 3.0.9.2 version for regular use. And `snap` version when there is a need to take screenshots from a video.

---

**Update**: There is build-in screenshot function in VLC player that is normally working also in VLC 3.0.9.2:

```
Menu -> Video -> Take Screenshot
```

Shortcut for Linux: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

Screenshots are saved also to the standard folder:

```
/home/user-name/Pictures
```

Additional details:

- [How to take a screenshot of a fullscreen video?](https://askubuntu.com/q/240725/355121)